# What is the type of a list in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to declare a list of strings in a `plpgsql` script and I don't know which type is correct. I tried this:

```
do $$
declare
    my_list text[] = ('a', 'b', 'c');
begin
    ...
end
$$ language plpgsql
```

It gives the error:

```
Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

The type `text[]` is an array that I should define with `{` and `}` symbols. But what is the type that suits `(` and `)` definition as in my example?

Comment: Maybe You are looking for VALUES list? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/queries-values.html

Comment: Likely. So what is the correct data type for it to declare?

Comment: @Fomalhaut: the array type is correct, you need to initialize it correctly however. What exactly do you want to do with that list?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The only thing I am going to do is to check the presence in the list: `select ... where a in my_list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is the correct type to use:

```
my_list text[] := array['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

This can be used for an "IN type" condition, you just need to use the ANY operator.

```
....
where a = any(my_list)
```

That is effectively the same as `where a in ('a','b','c')` - in fact the `IN` operator gets re-written to an ANY operator by the query optimimzer.